# PyQt - Combining QSlider and QTextEdit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a `QSlider`-`QTextEdit` synchronised pair, such that any change in one is reflected in the other. This is the code I have:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

        self.main_panel = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_panel)

        grid = QGridLayout(self.main_panel)

        self.sl = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.txt = QTextEdit(self)

        self._old_val = ""
        self.sl.valueChanged.connect(self._sl_to_txt)
        self.txt.textChanged.connect(self._txt_to_sl)

        self.sl.setMinimum(1)
        self.sl.setMaximum(60)
        self.sl.setValue(30)

        grid.addWidget(self.sl, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.txt, 0, 1)

    def _sl_to_txt(self, val):
        print("SL->TXT")
        self.txt.setText(str(val))

    def _txt_to_sl(self):
        print("TXT->SL")
        val = self.txt.toPlainText()
        try:
            self.sl.setValue(int(val))
            self._old_val = val
        except ValueError:
            self.txt.setText(self._old_val)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, this causes both signals to be emitted at the same time (due to `setValue` and `setText` triggering the respective signals) and also for some reason keeps placing the cursor to the start of the text area when trying to type into it.

How do I change the text/slider value without triggering the corresponding signals?

Comment: You can use `widget.blockSignals(True)` before changing the target widget and `widget.blockSignals(False)` after that, but I'm afraid that this won't improve much, as your approach will result as very confusing to the user (it seems some kind of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Why are you ising a QPlainTextEdit for such a thing? You could use QSpinBox instead, which will result in a much simpler implementation.

Comment: ' setText' resets the cursor. You could memorize the position of the text cursor and then reset it to the same position, if that's what you wanted.